# How to create another update function with PUT and PATCH request in one route?

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, put

I am currently developing a project using **laravel 5.0**. Lets say i have a route like this in my route.php:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'destroy']]);
Route::get('user/{user}/posts', 'UserController@indexUserPosts');
Route::get('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@changePassword');
Route::put('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@updatePassword');
Route::patch('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@updatePassword');
```

Where if i access `http:// localhost:8000/user/{username}` it will trigger the show method, and if i access `http://localhost:8000/user/{username}/edit` it will trigger the edit method which will give a `PUT` & `PATCH` request to `http:// localhost:8000/user/{user}`. But in this phase, the user can only edit their personal informations, for the password i want to create a new `editPassword` which gives also `PUT` & `PATCH` request. And im not sure if i write the route correctly above.

So, the question is how do i manually write the route in the route.php file according to laravel's convention?

And should i send the `PUT` & `PATCH` request to `http: //localhost:8000/user/{user}` again (which i think will crash with the `PUT` & `PATCH` request from the edit function) or should i send the `PUT` & `PATCH` request to http: `//localhost:8000/user/{user}/changepassword` ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need to repeat `patch` function. It's enough to use `put`. The second thing is, whenever you create any extra urls and user resource, you need to put them before resource route, so your routes file should look like this:

```
Route::get('user/{user}/posts', 'UserController@indexUserPosts');
Route::get('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@changePassword');
Route::put('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@update');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'destroy']]);
```

So now, when user go to edit page, they will have link to edit password page, when they click on it they will go to GET `user/{user}/changepassword` and when they fill form and click update they will go to `PUT user/{user}/changepassword'`

Comment: Actually i've tried to use only the put function in the routes, so my routes looked like this:
 Route::get('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@changePassword');
 Route::put('user/{user}/changepassword', 'UserController@updatePassword');
 Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'destroy']]);

But in my change password forms, im actually using a PATCH request which i learned from the laracasts site. And it doesnt work, when i tried to change the PATCH into PUT it did work, so should i include those two?